# How to rename file in jquery file upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, uploadify, jquery-file-upload

> Hi i'm new to jquery. i'm trying to rename the file in upload..but i'm not able to do so
>
> The Code i'm using for file upload

```
 $(function() {
var btnUpload=$('#upload');

var status=$('#status');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
action: 'upload-file.php',
name: 'uploadfile',
    onSubmit: function(finalname, ext){
if (! (ext && /^(pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|text|)$/.test(ext))){ 
status.text('Only pdf, xls,doc,docs,xlsx and text files are allowed');
return false;
}
status.text('Uploading...');
},
onComplete: function(finalname, response){
status.text('');
if(response==="success"){
$('#head').val(finalname);
} else{
status.text('Upload Failed');
}
    }
});
```

> Php Code is

```
$uploaddir = 'uploads/files/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {

    echo "error";
}
```

> Html

```
<div id="upload" ><span>Browse<span></div><span id="status" ></span>
<input type="text" id="head" name="head" value="">
```

> i am able to rename with php file...but not in jquery code it gives me wrong file name kindly help

Comment: People are not here to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I managed to rename the file name before upload...pepole down voted it inspite of helping. The changed i made to my code might be usefull for someone else

```
 $(function() {
    var btnUpload=$('#upload');
var status=$('#status');
var mm=Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + new Date().getTime(); //to add new name of file
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
action: 'upload-file.php?name='+mm, // gave a action to php file so i can use the same name
name: 'uploadfile',
onSubmit: function(file, ext){
 if (! (ext && /^(pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|text|)$/.test(ext))){ 
status.text('Only pdf, xls,doc,docs,xlsx and text files are allowed');
return false;
}
status.text('Uploading...');
},
onComplete: function(file, response){
var fileExtension = '.' + file.split('.').pop(); //got the file extestion
var outputfile = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.')) || file; //got the file name
var spaceremoved=outputfile.replace(/\s/g, '');//removed the space from file
var filename=mm+spaceremoved+fileExtension; //merged all to one
    status.text('');
if(response==="success"){
    $('#head').val(filename);
    } else{
}
    }
    });
```

> changes i made in php file

```
$uploaddir = 'uploads/files/'; 
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
$filena=$_GET['name'];
}
$basename=$filena.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);//merged the name
$finalna=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $basename);//removed the space
$file = $uploaddir .$finalna;// merged to final 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```